# flexbox remove vertical space on flex-wrap

Tags: css, flexbox, vuetify.js

i have a question about flexbox...

does anyone know how to remove the vertical space on flex-wrap? is there any magical flex attr. or third party library?
at the moment i am using vuetify and custom css but i want the space been filled by the card below.

i tried different flexbox properties but couldn't find the right one

[image: image of flexbox]

Answer (score -1):

When you are working in a single-line flex container (i.e., flex-wrap: nowrap)
When you are working in a more than one line flex container (i.e., flex-wrap: wrap)
display: inline-flex;
flex-wrap: wrap;